# SOAP UI method to generate random alphanumeric value

Tags: soapui

Can anyone please tell me what is the method to generate random alphanumeric number for request file in SOAP UI?

To be specific I need one tag value to be like 'ADS02018282' where ASD should be constant and rest should be random numeric number.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Groovy one-liner to generate the random number. Either of the following should work:

```
ADS${=(int)(Math.random() * 100000000).padLeft(8, '0')}
ADS${=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(8)}
```